# MFC drawn elements change after 30-60 minutes

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, gdi

I have an application with a completely custom drawn UI (i.e. just a bunch of filled boxes with text).  After about 30-60 minutes of running time, the UI elements spontaneously change.  For example, the white lines (box borders) disappear, the text resizes, etc.

I have linked to some before and after images of one of the screens.  This one shows that all of the white lines have disappeared.  Other screens show significant changes in text size.

BEFORE: http://s21.postimg.org/cogqodson/BEFORE.png

AFTER: http://s24.postimg.org/7skx21sid/AFTER.png

This project is written in MS Visual C++ 2010 using MFC, and running on Windows 7 Pro.

Here is my OnPaint() code:

```
void CMainWindow::OnPaint()
{
    CPaintDC dcScreen( this );
    CBitmap bitmap;
    bitmap.CreateCompatibleBitmap( &dcScreen, m_rect.Width(), m_rect.Height() );

    CDC dc;
    dc.CreateCompatibleDC( &dcScreen );
    CBitmap* pOldBitMap = dc.SelectObject( &bitmap );

    dc.FillRect(m_rect, &BGBRUSH);
    int bkmode = dc.SetBkMode(TRANSPARENT);
    dc.SelectObject(&BGBRUSH);

    CPen brightwhitepen(PS_SOLID, 5, RGB(255,255,255));
    CPen* pOldPen = dc.SelectObject(&brightwhitepen);

    // draw some stuff:
    // dc.Rectangle, dc.DrawText, etc.
    // ...

    // Blit the memory device context to the screen device context
    dcScreen.BitBlt
        (
        0, 
        0, 
        m_rect.Width(), 
        m_rect.Height(),
        &dc, 
        0, 
        0, 
        SRCCOPY
        );

    dc.SetBkMode( bkmode );     // Restore old background mode
    dc.SelectObject( pOldPen ); // reselect old pen
    dc.SelectObject( pOldBitMap ); // Restore old bitmap
}
```

Has anyone seen weird behavior like this before?  Any tips on where to investigate?

Thanks!

Comment: My suspicion is that somehow you're not freeing your resources completely and every paint call leaks. After a certain point, it just starts failing to allocate new pens, bitmaps, etc... But I'm not sure how that could be given you're using all the MFC wrapper classes for the win32 primitive handles. Check tack manager and see what your process is doing memory wise. Maybe Process Explorer allows you to view the number of open handles?

Comment: That was my initial thought too, but if I watch Task Manager, the memory usage is fine.  In fact, during my last test, the memory usage was exactly the same before and after the UI messing up.

Comment: eliminate drawing code until problem disappears, in taskmanager look at gdi handles count rather at memory usage - not sure the actual name of that column, might be different

Comment: Yes!  Thank you "cppguy" and "marcin_j"!  For one special item, I was using the GDI functions to create my pen ("ExtCreatePen()") instead of the MFC classes, and of course, I forgot to call "DeleteObject()" for that object.  With your guidance I was able to watch the "GDI Objects" count in Task Manager climb to 10000 over 55 minutes, at which point it would max out and the UI would stop drawing properly.  Thanks again!!!

Answer (score 2):

I've solved a problem like this once before when I forgot to restore the state of one of the GDI handles. The solution was to use `SaveDC` and `RestoreDC`, which means you won't have to restore any of the objects in the DC after you're done with them. You can download a [really convenient RAII class](http://www.flounder.com/savedc.htm) here that does all the work for you.

A secondary suggestion is to use the stock objects and built-in DC handles rather than creating your own. So replace your `brightwhitepen` code like this:

```
dc.SetDCPenColor(RGB(255,255,255));
CPen* pBrightwhitepen = CPen::FromHandle((HPEN)GetStockObject(DC_PEN));

dc.SetDCBrushColor(RGB(0,0,255));
CBrush* pBgBrush = CBrush::FromHandle((HBRUSH)GetStockObject(DC_BRUSH));
```

Now use these two pointers to draw your stuff. The advantage is that you didn't allocate anything, so you can't leak anything, and the calls can't fail because the stock objects always exist.